# Awk: ilegal variable reference error in Ubuntu but works OK in MinGW-64

Tags: ubuntu, awk, mingw-w64

This script runs flawlessly in MinGW-64 but it fails in Ubuntu with

```
awk: /home/username/chuleta/chuleta/glst.awk: line 22: illegal reference to variable a

awk: /home/username/chuleta/chuleta/glst.awk: line 23: illegal reference to variable a
```

...even after changing the shebang from `#!/usr/bin/gawk -f` to `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` to discard it being an implementation difference between GNU Awk and non-GNU Awk.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# generates list of terms related to a topic

# this funcion substitutes a with b in $0
func change(a,b) {
    while (i=index($0,a))
            $0 = substr($0,1,i-1) b substr($0,i+length(a))
}

{
    # we delete the base folder (received in var RTO) from the input line
    # and clean it of other stuff
    change(RTO,"")
    change(".txt","")
    change("/"," ")
    change("_"," ")
    split($0,a," ")
    # using arr as associative array by using same string as index
    # this prevents duplicated strings and code is shorter
    # since we don't have to maintain a counter for index
    for (x in a)  # this is line 22
        arr[a[x]]=a[x] # this is line 23
}

END{
    n=asort(arr,sarr)
    for (x in sarr)
        printf("%s ",sarr[x])
}
```

Variable `a` is supposed to be an array resulting from splitting $0 using space as a delimited.

What is happening? As already mentioned, this error doesn't happen in WinGW-64 (the Linux  bash emulation used by Git for Windows).

EDIT:

An example data set that is piped thru that Awk script is as follows:

```
/home/username/chuleta/chuleta-data/java/8/chuleta_foreach_loop.txt
/home/username/chuleta/chuleta-data/java/8/chuleta_basic_functional_interfaces_in_function_package.txt
/home/username/chuleta/chuleta-data/java/8/chuleta_advantages_new_date_time_api.txt
/home/username/chuleta/chuleta-data/java/8/chuleta_new_date_time_api.txt
/home/username/chuleta/chuleta-data/java/8/chuleta_solve_interface_default_methods_conflict.txt
/home/username/chuleta/chuleta-data/java/8/chuleta_lambdas_with_parameters.txt
```

`RTO` passed to the script holding the base dir (`home/username/chuleta/chuleta-data/`), then removes it from the beginning, then removes ".txt", changes "/" and "-" into spaces and then the resulting space-separated words list is split into an array ("a") which is later used to populate an associative array. Basically we get a space-separated list of subfolder names excluding the base dir, for example "java 8 chuleta foreach loop". Resulting `a` array contains those five items. Those code lines where `a` is traversed are the ones that fail only in Ubuntu but not in MinGW-64.

EDIT 2:

Output in Ubuntu 22.04, awk version mawk 1.3.4 20200120, GNU bash, version 5.1.16:

```
$ cat data.txt | ./program.awk -v RTO=/home/username/chuleta/chuleta-data
awk: ./prueba.sh: line 18: illegal reference to variable a
awk: ./prueba.sh: line 22: illegal reference to variable a
awk: ./prueba.sh: line 23: illegal reference to variable a
awk: ./prueba.sh: line 23: illegal reference to variable a
```

Output in MINGW64_NT-10.0-19044 3.1.7-340, awk version GNU Awk 5.0.0, API: 2.0, GNU bash, version 4.4.23:

```
$ cat data.txt | ./program.awk -v RTO=/home/username/chuleta/chuleta-data
8 advantages api basic chuleta conflict date default foreach function functional in interface interfaces java lambdas loop methods new package parameters solve time with
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output. Thanks. Also, for example mawk does not recognize `func` for `function` - or `asort` You need to use gawk for those (well, for `asort` anyway).

Comment: @JamesBrown Added sample data and how it is cleaned and split into an array. Hope it helps.

Comment: please update the question with *a)* `awk` version (`awk --version`), *b)* an example of how you're calling your script from the command line and *c)* the expected output (corresponding to the sample input)

Comment: fwiw, in my env (Ubuntu, bash 5.0.17, GNU awk 5.0.1) this code runs with no errors

Comment: @markp-fuso Added usage and output in both platforms, including versions of utilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script uses GNU Awk features which are not available in Mawk.

The simple fix is probably `apt-get install -y gawk` in your Ubuntu installation, and make sure you `update-alternatives` to ensure that `awk` points to `gawk`.

In some more detail, renaming `a` to `k` in the main function removes the immediate problem with Mawk, but it then complains that `asort` is never defined. (This function is a GNU Awk extension.)